# Yolov3.weights not being read fully error

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, yolo

When running the code from the main.py file an error occurs in the utils.py file in which the yolov3.weights file is not read. This error occurs in the utils.py file in the load_yolo_weights function. The weights_file directs the program to the correct file location. The YOLO_TYPE is yolov3

Provided bellow is the code.

main.py:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import sys
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from yolov3.utils import Load_Yolo_model

# starting deep sort
maxCosineDist = 0.7
nn_budget = None

modelFilename = 'mars-small128.pb'
encoder = gendetect.create_box_encoder(modelFilename, batch_size=1)
metric = nn_matching.NearestNeighborDistanceMetric("cosine", maxCosineDist, nn_budget)
tracker = Tracker(metric)

yolo = Load_Yolo_model()

# Read image

out = "Yolo_Output.avi"
if args.image:
    if not os.path.isfile(args.image):
        print(args.image, " doesn't exist")
        sys.exit(1)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(args.image)
    out = args.image[:-4] + "Yolo_Output.jpg"

# Load class names
classesFile = "coco.names"
classes = read_class_names(classesFile)

keyList = list(classes.keys())
valList = list(classes.values())

# Create window for output
windowTitle = "Sports Tracking and Analytics"
cv2.namedWindow(windowTitle, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)


while True:
    _, frame = vid.read()

    try:
        origFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        origFrame = cv2.cvtColor(origFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    except:
        break

    imgData = image_preprocess(np.copy(origFrame), [416, 416])
    imgData = imgData[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)

    predBox = yolo.predict(imgData)
```

utils.py

```
import cv2
import time
import random
import colorsys

from yolov3.yolov4 import *
from yolov3.configs import *
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

def load_yolo_weights(model, weights_file):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session() # used to reset layer names
    # load Darknet original weights to TensorFlow model
    if YOLO_TYPE == "yolov3":
        range1 = 75 if not TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else 13
        range2 = [58, 66, 74] if not TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else [9, 12]
    if YOLO_TYPE == "yolov4":
        range1 = 110 if not TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else 21
        range2 = [93, 101, 109] if not TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else [17, 20]

    with open(weights_file, 'rb') as wf:
        major, minor, revision, seen, _ = np.fromfile(wf, dtype=np.int32, count=5)

        j = 0
        for i in range(range1):
            if i > 0:
                conv_layer_name = 'conv2d_%d' %i
            else:
                conv_layer_name = 'conv2d'

            if j > 0:
                bn_layer_name = 'batch_normalization_%d' %j
            else:
                bn_layer_name = 'batch_normalization'

            conv_layer = model.get_layer(conv_layer_name)
            filters = conv_layer.filters
            k_size = conv_layer.kernel_size[0]
            in_dim = conv_layer.input_shape[-1]

            if i not in range2:
                # darknet weights: [beta, gamma, mean, variance]
                bn_weights = np.fromfile(wf, dtype=np.float32, count=4 * filters)
                # tf weights: [gamma, beta, mean, variance]
                bn_weights = bn_weights.reshape((4, filters))[[1, 0, 2, 3]]
                bn_layer = model.get_layer(bn_layer_name)
                j += 1
            else:
                conv_bias = np.fromfile(wf, dtype=np.float32, count=filters)

            # darknet shape (out_dim, in_dim, height, width)
            conv_shape = (filters, in_dim, k_size, k_size)
            conv_weights = np.fromfile(wf, dtype=np.float32, count=np.product(conv_shape))
            # tf shape (height, width, in_dim, out_dim)
            conv_weights = conv_weights.reshape(conv_shape).transpose([2, 3, 1, 0])

            if i not in range2:
                conv_layer.set_weights([conv_weights])
                bn_layer.set_weights(bn_weights)
            else:
                conv_layer.set_weights([conv_weights, conv_bias])

        assert len(wf.read()) == 0, 'failed to read all data'

def Load_Yolo_model():
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if len(gpus) > 0:
        print(f'GPUs {gpus}')
        try: tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
        except RuntimeError: pass

    if YOLO_FRAMEWORK == "tf": # TensorFlow detection
        if YOLO_TYPE == "yolov4":
            Darknet_weights = YOLO_V4_TINY_WEIGHTS if TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else YOLO_V4_WEIGHTS
        if YOLO_TYPE == "yolov3":
            Darknet_weights = YOLO_V3_TINY_WEIGHTS if TRAIN_YOLO_TINY else YOLO_V3_WEIGHTS

        if YOLO_CUSTOM_WEIGHTS == False:
            print("Loading Darknet_weights from:", Darknet_weights)
            yolo = Create_Yolo(input_size=416, CLASSES="coco.names")
            load_yolo_weights(yolo, Darknet_weights) # use Darknet weights
        else:
            checkpoint = f"./checkpoints/{TRAIN_MODEL_NAME}"
            if TRAIN_YOLO_TINY:
                checkpoint += "_Tiny"
            print("Loading custom weights from:", checkpoint)
            yolo = Create_Yolo(input_size=416, CLASSES=TRAIN_CLASSES)
            yolo.load_weights(checkpoint)  # use custom weights

    elif YOLO_FRAMEWORK == "trt": # TensorRT detection
        saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(YOLO_CUSTOM_WEIGHTS, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
        signature_keys = list(saved_model_loaded.signatures.keys())
        yolo = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']

    return yolo
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the complete error log to investigate the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

The error was caused by the coco.names file as the one I was using was previously edited.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what was wrong with the file in question? You might want to explicitly state what parts did you change or remove from the file so that you can help others experiencing a similar issue.